# Kendo UI for Angular2 Grid Web API databinding

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I see in the KendoUI for Angular 2 sample (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/) the grid binds to an oData service.  Is there a way to bind to a plain Web API restful service instead?

My back-end is an ASP.Net Core (full framework) service, which does not support oData services yet (based on this: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/772)

Answer (score 0):

That implementation is based on Angular's Http service, so you should be able to do the same with any REST end point. The Kendo UI Grid does not really care about the particular endpoint, and just waits for the JSON data to be passed.

Comment: But its more a case of an incompatibility between the server call (url) that the grid datasource generates, and the server code itself....the url that is generated is as per the oData v4 spec, but it is not yet possible to build such an oData v4 endpoint in .Net Core.

Comment: The back-end doesn't have to be a full-blown oData v4 endpoint. It only has to support the operations that the Grid uses - paging in this case.

Comment: There's also the ToDataSourceResult helper from our ASP.NET MVC / Core suites. It provides an alternative for server-side processing and works in ASP.NET Core. See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/binding/web-api-server-operations

The missing piece is support for it in the Kendo UI for Angular 2 suite. This is on our roadmap and will land in the next few months.

Comment: When you have data returned either in a subscribe next or promise resolve, you can get the grid to work with pagination by converting your data to a GridDataResult type. This may have come out since you asked your question.